# How to configure/disable file caching in WebLogic 12.2

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic, devops, weblogic12c

I'm working with WebLogic 12.2.1.3 and I know any web files (jsp, js, css etc) are cached by default in these two locations:

```
ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/your_domain/servers/your_server/tmp
ORACLE_HOME/user_projects/domains/your_domain/servers/your_server/cache
```

Is there any way to disable this caching? Or to set a constant path from where the cached resources are always taken?

Whenever I change something in such files I need to either stop the server, rebuild and redeploy or to search where the file I want to modify is located in the cache, do the modifications there and then copy them to my source project. First way is pretty slow and the second way is proned to errors like forgetting to copy all the changes to my project and not finding the cache file since the path changes dynamically...
In WebLogic 12.1.3 I used to deploy an exploded war file, then I would just synchronize changes in my source project with that folder without needing to restart...

Comment: There is no way to disable this caching system. It is not possible to change the location of tmp files also. You would never update these files by your own.
Deployment has not been changed between 12.1.x and 12.2.x
You always can deploy your application as an exploded war using the console or WLST.

Comment: Thx @EmmanuelCollin. I still can deploy the exploded war however if I modify a js/jsp file inside the exploded war, the change is not visible in the application. For 12.1.3 this was working and it was a fast way to try out changes without a full rebuild and redeploy

Comment: Does your 12.1.3 domain runs in dev mode with fastSwap enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EmmanuelCollin's comment helped. Change your domain to dev mode (uncheck production). You still have to do Ctrl+F5 on your browser to see the changes, but the changes are immediate.